# import a.fun is not the same as from a import fun?

Tags: python, import

I use python 3.7.6.

I have two files in the same directory: `a.py` and `b.py`.
In `a.py`:

```
def fun():
  print('successfully call this function')
```

In `b.py`:

```
import a.fun
```

when I run `b.py`, error occurs:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.fun'; 'a' is not a package`
However after I change `b.py` to

```
from a import fun
```

and run `b.py` again, it works normally.

I want to know why. I thought `import a.fun` is the same as `from a import fun`, but this experiment shows that maybe I am wrong.

------first edit-----
after I change `b.py` to

```
import a
a.fun()
```

and run `b.py` again, it also works normally.

In summary, two methods work normally:
`from a import fun`
and

```
import a
a.fun
```

but `import a.fun` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` clause (thanks @user2357112supportsMonica for correction) only accepts modules, not just any identifier. That's why the interpreter complains that it couldn't find the module specified. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement.

Comment: Wrong way around.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica how so? The documentation I linked states a from...import statement will "find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary"

Comment: The *`from` clause* only accepts modules, but the thing in the `from` clause is `a`, not `fun`.

Comment: Is it a bug? I hope,  one day, 'from a import fun' would be the same as 'import a.fun'.

Comment: The `from` import works fine, because `from a import fun` doesn't require `fun` to be a module. It's `import a.fun` that requires `fun` to be a submodule of `a`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Why python has such setting? Why `import a.fun` is not acceptable when `fun` is a function in `a.py`?

Answer (score -1):

Summarizing from the answer by riftEmber, "import a.fun" only works if you have a file called a.fun, "import" is what it says, it will import the file, whereas "from a import fun" is different. "from a" calls up the file a, then "import fun" open the file a and then import the function "fun". Basically "import" imports the file, whereas "from a import fun" gets the file a, then runs the function "fun". Hopefully this makes sense.